# Android - How to get ripple effect on GridView items?

Tags: android, gridview, material-design

I have implemented image gallery using GridView. The layout for the grid item:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/media_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/thumbnail_for_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/overlay_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" />
</FrameLayout>
```

My goal is to get this nice material ripple effect upon touching the grid item.
Unfortunately, I couldn't manage to find pure solution for my problem.
So I came up with using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847151/ripple-effect-on-top-of-image-android), as author says, work around - adding overlay **View** on top of main **ImageView**, and setting background to

`?attr/selectableItemBackground`

Putting it to ImageView's background or parent FrameLayout background didn't work.

I'm sure, there must be a better way to handle it.

Comment: Try putting it to `FrameLayout`'s foreground. Like this.
`android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`.

Comment: @siris_cac That actually worked, thanks!
Any idea how to force it make circle waves upon touching?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain?

Comment: @siris_cac I've checked your solution carefully. It occured that it worked on some of the items and did not on the others. I really don't know why.
So I found anoher solution, that worked fine.
adding `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` to the GridView did the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ripple effect on top of Image - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27847151/ripple-effect-on-top-of-image-android)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` in GridView did the trick

Answer (score 1):

If you want this ripple to be supported in pre-lollipop versions I suggest you to use ripple libraries like [The ones here](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=ripple). I guess using `?attr/selectableItemBackground` won't give you ripple on pre-L androids.

Comment: thanks, but I'm aware of that. I was looking for the way to make it work on Lollipop.