# CardView's background which will respond to android:state_selected and android:state_pressed

Tags: android

I'm referring to the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24475228/72437

The proposed answer is using drawable from Android : `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground`

[image]

This is what happen when I tap on the card item. Note that, by using drawable from Android, `android:state_selected="true"` (when `setSelected(true)`) will not have any color change effect.

Hence, I would like to use my own defined drawable so that

1. It looks nicer.
2. Able to handle `android:state_selected="true"`.

Here's my code

---

### statelist_item_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_background" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_background" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

### selected_background.xml

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffe1b3" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#fff76d3c" />
</shape>
```

### card_row.xml

```
<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="@drawable/statelist_item_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_label_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            tools:text="Item Number One" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_date_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            tools:text="Item Number One" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

When I long press on the card item and perform `childView.setSelected(true);`, here's my outcome.

[image]

All my card content (`TextView`s) are blocked. How can I avoid such?

### Some notes regarding using android:background

Note, when you use `android:background="@drawable/statelist_item_background"` with `CardView` itself, nothing will happen.

However, if you use `android:background="@drawable/statelist_item_background"` with `CardView`'s `LinearLayout`, **you will get the following imperfect outcome**.

[image]

**The highlighted color doesn't cover the entire card**.

### Update

Seem like this is limitation of `CardView` - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78198 Using "foreground" as workaround is not an option as it covers card content.

Comment: What are you setting your card view background to with the changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After experimenting for quite some time, I can pretty much conclude that this is limitation of current `CardView` - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78198

Don't use `CardView`'s foreground workaround. Although it is widely being proposed, it just don't work!

My suggestion is, avoid using `CardView` if you need a customized selector. Replace it `LayerDrawable`. Here's what I had done.

### card.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffededed" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffe8e8e8" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffe1e1e1" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="0dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffdbdbdb" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="0dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffd5d5d5" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!--
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="0dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffcfcfcf" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    -->

    <item>
        <shape >
            <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

### card_selected.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffededed" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffe8e8e8" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffe1e1e1" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="0dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffdbdbdb" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="0dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffd5d5d5" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!--
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="0dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffcfcfcf" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    -->

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ffffe1b3" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1px"
                android:color="#fff76d3c" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

### statelist_item_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/card_selected" />     <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/card_selected" />     <!-- pressed -->

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/card" />

</selector>
```

### layout.xml

```
<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/statelist_item_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_label_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        tools:text="Item Number One" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_date_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        tools:text="Item Number One" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You will get the pretty nice outcome.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried `MaterialCardView` and this works:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/material_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/selector_background_color"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp">
```

selector_background_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_activated="true"/>
<item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_activated="false"/>
```

In the Activity/Fragment:

```
material_card_view.setOnClickListener {
        it.isActivated = !it.isActivated
}
```

For the `strokeColor` though, you can't use a selector. You will have to do it programmatically if you want the stroke color to change as per selector state.

Example for state_activated:

```
val colorStateList: ColorStateList = 
ResourcesCompat.getColorStateList(resources, 
R.color.selector_stroke_color, null)!!
val colorForState =colorStateList.getColorForState(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_activated), colorStateList.defaultColor)
material_card_view.strokeColor = colorForState
```

Answer (score 0):

> All my card content (TextViews) are blocked. How can I avoid such?

Your blocked issue can easily be solved with some color theory knowledge. Instead of using the given peach color, you could use a variant of the peach shade with a higher transparency.

Color Code scheme in Android xxyyyyyy

xx is your transparency level, and y's are your color.

xx max value is : ff // this is fully visible

xx min value is : 00 // this is full invisible

So by playing around on the color wheel, you can get the right effect with the right amount of transparency needed for your view.

Comment: Using alpha value won't help. If you use non zero alpha value, the text view seems to block by a "blur" layer. If you use zero alpha value (full transparent), there is no color at all.

Answer (score 0):

for the background not covering the entire card issue, it is due to the cornerRadius drawing limitation. There are two solutions for this:

1. Disable round corner for your card will resolve the problem. `app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"`
2. You can retain cardCornerRadius but you need to set `app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"`

Answer (score 0):

`MaterialCardView` has ripple effect and doesn't need a custom background drawable as opposed to `CardView`.
That handled the `android:state_selected` and `android:state_pressed` for my use case.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are misunderstanding the question you referred to. The question is how to get the ripple effect:

[image: enter link description here]

**Where I think you are just looking for click feedback?** 
If so, try setting the background drawable:

```
  android:background="@drawable/statelist_item_background"
```

### EDIT:

On you background color xml, you need to give it an alpha. It is being drawn in the front, so give it an alpha of `.1f` and see how that looks and go from there.
Try using color `50F76D3C` Then use is it in the foreground like you were originally.

Comment: Using `android:background` won't help much. I update my finding in question regarding using `android:background`

Comment: Using alpha value won't help. If you use non zero alpha value, the text view seems to block by a "blur" layer. If you use zero alpha value (full transparent), there is no color at all.