# How to have padding for ripple effect

Tags: android

Previously, I'm using `StateDrawable` to achieve custom card view with shadow effect - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33829309/72437 . This is due to the limitation of `CardView`, of not able to accept selector in its `cardBackgroundColor`

Now, I want to add ripple effect. I use the following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#00ff00">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/statelist_item_background"/>
</ripple>
```

However, this is having side effect where the green ripple extends till it touches shadow region.

I want to avoid the green ripple from touching shadow region. I try to add in padding information.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#00ff00">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding android:top="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/statelist_item_background"/>
</ripple>
```

[image]

However, it makes no different. Adding padding information within `ripple` tag makes no difference.

May I know how can I have padding for ripple effect?

Comment: use layout_margin. The ripple effect will not go beyond your margins

Comment: Did you got any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `inset` tag to define the padding you need. There is an `inset` attribute to define global padding or 4 attributes for each directions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:inset="10dp">
    <ripple
        android:color="#00ff00">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/statelist_item_background"/>
    </ripple>
</inset>
```

Answer (score 0):

First create the drawable file (ex: bg_ripple.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:inset="4dp">

    <ripple android:color="@color/gray_light">    

        <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <!-- this color does not matter, it's a mask shape -->
                <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/button_corner_radius" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:id="@android:id/background">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/button_corner_radius" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/red"
                    />
                <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </item>

    </ripple>
</inset>
```

Second add it as a background to the Button

```
<Button        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/click_me"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_ripple"
    />
```

Answer (score -4):

You should add this to your CarView:

```
<CardView
    ...
    style="@style/MyCardViewStyle"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
</CardView>
```

And then, add this in your style:

```
<style name="MyCardViewStyle">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/my_awesome_color</item>
</style>
```

It will give you the awesome color you want to your ripple effect, without having to create yourself your ripple, and the bounds will automatically be detected so you won't need to find if it's even possible to add a padding to the ripple.

Comment: I do not use card view. Please see my question again

Comment: You are saying that it doesn't support selector in backgroundColor. It it did, you would use it, right?

Comment: Yes. If CardView accepts selector in backgroundColor, I prefer not to go through all hassle, in achieving shadowing effect using StateDrawable. However, I'm 100% sure with current state, CardView not able to do so according to the issue reporting in android - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78198

Comment: For shadow on pressed state, you can extend CardView and animate elevation on state changes. For ripple, I suggest you to use foreground attribute instead, it gives a better user feedback as the ripple is visible, whatever is in the CardView. Note that your CardView not having shadow feedback on pressed state is not mandatory. I'm using foreground ripple alone in my app. Also, don't over cardify your UI (see Material Design Guidelines). It seems that you are putting very few content in your cards, which are in a list. Adding CardViee here prevents quick eye scanning for user.

Comment: Using card view foreground won't work. It will block card view content if you tend to use non transparent color.

Comment: Did you tried with my snippet (`android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`)? I know that you didn't, but you should. Behind this attribute is a ripple state drawable, which won't show until you press the FrameLayout (CardView is a FrameLayout subclass). When you press it, the content will still be visible behind, because ripples aren't fully opaque. Neither selectable background (as a foreground here) are fully opaque on pre-Lollipop. Test it, please.

Comment: I don't want use card view. I need different UI when the view is in different stage : activated, selected, ...

Comment: You are so complicated... You show me a CardView screenshot, but finally, you don't want it, and it's only now, after 6 comments that you say it... FrameLayout supports the same behavior, but you'll have to use layout_margin to change ripple bounds. Anyway, I don't exactly what you want to get, but it doesn't seem to be the good approach to me. You can still try using xml drawables among the different available types and set ripple there.

Comment: U didn't read my question carefully. I already stated I didn't use card view in the very beginning.

Comment: But you didn't explained what you use and why you don't use CardView